# How to select from subclass entity property using Spring Data / JPQL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I need to query on a property of a subclass. Here are the entities involved:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Course {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
    private Person person;

}

@Entity
@Data
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

}

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
public class Student extends Person {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="studentTypeId")
    private StudentType studentType;
            
}

@Entity
@Data
public class StudentType {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Convert(converter = StudentTypeConverter.class)
    private StudentTypeEnum name;
    
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public static enum StudentTypeEnum {
        GRADUATE("Graduate");
        
        private final String name;
        
    }

}
```

I'm trying to query using a Spring Data repository:

```
public interface CourseRepository extends Repository<Course>  {
    
    List<Course> findByCoursePersonStudentTypeName(@Param("studentTypeName") String studentTypeName);
}
```

This doesn't work though. It generates an error stating `No property StudentTypeName found for Person!`. This makes sense since the property exists only on `Student`.

How can I write this method (preferably) or use JPQL to find the courses by type of student?

Comment: Should the Person in your Course be Student?

Comment: @pirho - No. In my case, it usually is a Student but I need the flexibility for other types of people to attend.

Comment: Why do you wrap `StudentTypeEnum` with `StudentType`? What is the role of `StudentTypeConverter`, what does it do? Is it jsut that you can use enum `name` as String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
@Query("select c from Course c join c.person as p where UPPER(p.studentType.name) = UPPER(?1)")
List<Course> findByCoursePersonStudentTypeName(String studentTypeName);
```

This uses a feature of Hibernate called implict casting.

Comment: This works great. Could you please provide a link to Hibernate documentation discussing implicit casting?

Comment: There is unfortunately no documentation about this that I could find. I'll create an issue for adding documentation about this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14699

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Query("select c from Course c join c.person as p, Student s where p.id = s.id and s.studentType.name = ?1")
List<Course> findByCoursePersonStudentTypeName(StudentTypeEnum studentTypeEnum);
```

Comment: +1 This is close. If I change, the parameter type from `String` to `StudentTypeEnum` it works. But I really would like to keep the parameter as a `String` and let the converter convert to a `StudentTypeEnum`.

Comment: @James updated the answer using StudentTypeEnum

Comment: Thanks. But this requires me to pass in `GRADUATE`. I would like to be able to pass in `Graduate`, `graduate`, etc. The converter that I built ignores case. How would you modify the query to keep using `String` ?

Comment: @James what about invoking the aforementioned query by StudentTypeEnum passing the following `new StudentTypeConverter().convertToEntityAttribute(studentTypeString)` as parameter?

Comment: Yeah, that would normally work well. But the problem here is that this is directly exposed to the client via Spring Data Rest.

Answer (score 0):

The following query in the repository worked for me:

```
public interface CourseRepository extends Repository<Course, Long> {

    @Query("select c" +
            " from Course c" +
            " inner join Student s on c.person.id = s.id" +
            " where s.studentType is not null" +
            " and s.studentType.name = :studentTypeName")
    List<Course> findByCoursePersonStudentTypeName(@Param("studentTypeName") StudentType.StudentTypeEnum studentTypeName);

}
```

Below I am inserting the enumeration type converter code you indicated you use in the @Converter annotation:

```
public class StudentTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<StudentType.StudentTypeEnum, String> {

    private final Map<String, StudentType.StudentTypeEnum> groupByName = Arrays
            .stream(StudentType.StudentTypeEnum.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(StudentType.StudentTypeEnum::getName, type -> type));

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(StudentType.StudentTypeEnum attribute) {
        return attribute.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public StudentType.StudentTypeEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return groupByName.get(dbData);
    }
}
```

I also added one type to the enumeration

```
        GRADUATE("Graduate"),
        OTHER("Other type");
```

Below is given the method call and its result:

```
List<Course> result = courseRepository.findByCoursePersonStudentTypeName(StudentType.StudentTypeEnum.GRADUATE);
```

[image: result]

I also paste the data that was given in the database:

1. student_type
   [image: student_type]
2. person
   [image: person]
3. student
   [image: student]
4. course
   [image: course]

Answer (score 0):

Honestly speaking, your design voilated very basic Object Oriented principals and is problematic for future maintenance and scalability.

You are trying to use a super class `Person` to generify different sub types of Person who can register to a Course. But on the other side you want to find the Course linked to a specific subtype of Person which completely break the Generic setup. That's why the Java compiler cannot help you automatically link the query to the solid subtype and Java runtime gives you an exception because they don't know if any subtype of Person has a StudentType property. The language just refuses to do things which could lead to error or unexpected result.

As some other replies has pointed out, you can achieve what you want by using the facilities provided Hibernate (Or other ORM). But this solution is obviously an Anti-Pattern, because it leaks business knowledge into SQL queries.

It turns your design from Object Oriented to SQL Oriented.

My suggestion is to refactor your model, one option is to generified your course class which seems polymophism in your business domain:

```
public abstract class Course<T extends Person> {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
    private T person;
}

public class CourseRegisteredByStudent extends Course<Student> {
    
}

public class CourseRegisteredByStaff extends Course<Staff> {
   
}

public interface CousreRegsiteredByStudentRepositry extends Repository<CousreRegsiteredByStudent> { 
    List<CousreRegsiteredByStudent> findByType(@Param("studentTypeName") String studentTypeName);
}

...
```

Here is a link of the demo of how to use Hibernate Any mapping to handle generic typed entity.

https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/hibernate-any
(I borrow the link from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001162/1109002)

Although there is still some improvement space, this design split the concerns with clear boundaries and avoid leaking domain logic into Repository layer. When design domain models, if you have to write a custom SQL instead of default Repository functions provided by the persistence framework then you should stop and think if there is something wrong on the model design.